# How to make Swashbuckle generate correct OpenAPI schema for a Dictionary parameter?

Tags: swashbuckle, openapi

I have an ASP.NetCore action method that is defined as:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]Dictionary<string,string> values)
{
  return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values));
}
```

The expected query would be something like:

```
http://localhost:36541/api?values[someProperty]=123&values[someOther]=234
```

When I use Swashbuckle the resulting swagger.json file would end up like:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "Test API"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/api/Api": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "Api"
                ],
                "operationId": "ApiApiGet",
                "consumes": [],
                "produces": [],
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "values",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "object"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {}
}
```

But this doesn't validate using autorest or http://editor.swagger.io/

The error is:

```
Schema error at paths['/api/Api'].get.parameters[0]
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: type, name, in, required
Jump to line 14

Schema error at paths['/api/Api'].get.parameters[0].required
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: true
Jump to line 14

Schema error at paths['/api/Api'].get.parameters[0].in
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: body, header, formData, path
Jump to line 15

Schema error at paths['/api/Api'].get.parameters[0].type
should be equal to one of the allowed values
allowedValues: string, number, boolean, integer, array, file
Jump to line 17
```

It seems that it's missing the `additionalProperties` property according to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/

How can I make this query parameter be a valid OpenAPI / Swagger definition?

Comment: You are generating an OpenAPI 2.0 definition. 2.0 does not support objects (incl. dictionaries) in the query string. It's supported in OpenAPI 3.0 though. Does Swashbuckle support OpenAPI 3.0?

Comment: Thanks @Helen, was not aware. I will follow this issue https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/671  

Please make your comment an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comment from @Helen

Swashbuckle does not support the OpenAPI Specification (OAS) 3.0 yet, so you should not have objects (such as dictionaries) on the query string.

My recommendation change that action to a Post and get the values from the Body, also since your response is `IActionResult` consider using `SwaggerResponse` something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerResponse(200, typeof(Dictionary<string, string>), "This returns a dictionary.")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> values)
{
  return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values));
}
```

**Update:** 
I was also looking into the possibility of sending the GET with a body, and there seems to be a lot of debate about it:
[HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)